# как вставить svg через тег <img>?

Tags: html, svg, img

пробую вставить svg таким образом: `<img src="/assets/menu/menubutton.svg">` но при этом ничего не работает (файл assets находится в корне, всё остальное тоже верно).
возможно у меня присутствует ошибка в самом файле svg, что в нём должно быть?

код внутри файла svg выглядит так:

```html
    <svg width="60" height="60">
<line x1="20" y1="30" x2="50" y2="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" stroke-linecap="round"/>
<line x1="20" y1="40" x2="50" y2="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" stroke-linecap="round"/>
<line x1="20" y1="50" x2="50" y2="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" stroke-linecap="round"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Добавьте код файла SVG в вопрос, тогда можно будет определить в нём причина или в другом. Попробуйте сначала самостоятельный файл `menubutton.svg` просто открыть в браузере.

Comment: namespace необходим

Comment: что такое namespace?

Comment: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course

Answer (score 1):

Как комментировал @Stranger in the Q необходимо добавить `namespace` svg

`xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`

Второй параметр необходим, если вы будете использовать `<use>` и другие теги, которые ссылаются на источник по `ID` Так что лучше сразу привыкать писать оба атрибута, чтобы потом не мучиться в поисках ошибки SVG.

```html
  <svg width="60" height="60"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<line x1="20" y1="30" x2="50" y2="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" stroke-linecap="round"/>
<line x1="20" y1="40" x2="50" y2="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" stroke-linecap="round"/>
<line x1="20" y1="50" x2="50" y2="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" stroke-linecap="round"/>
</svg>
```

Я сохранил этот код в отдельный файл `menubutton.svg` и залил его на сервер.

Далее вызываю его, как вы хотели с помощью `<img>`

```html
<img src="https://svg-art.ru/files/menubutton.svg" />
```

Comment: @Panfiloff Если ответ вам был полезен, не забудьте нажать на галочку, рядом с треугольниками. Если ещё есть вопросы, - задавайте